# exchangelib KeyError: 'contacts' or KeyError: 'inbox' or

Tags: python-3.x, exchangelib

I want to search in contact list of some account and get that contacts details back, but none of folders that told [here](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#folders) not work because of `KeyError` exception .
Somehow i can't access to any of exchange account folders.

Is it permission or ... ?

Code :

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, Configuration
from exchangelib.protocol import NoVerifyHTTPAdapter, BaseProtocol

BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = NoVerifyHTTPAdapter

credentials = Credentials("YYY@XXX.com", 'PASSWORD')


account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address="Account@XXX.com",
    autodiscover=True, 
    credentials=credentials
)

print(account)  # work properly with printing my account
print(account.contacts)  # not work with KeyError Exception
```

Error :

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 857
    InsecureRequestWarning)
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cached_property.py", line 69, in __get__
    return obj_dict[name]
KeyError: 'contacts'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dvp7\Desktop\ex.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(account.contacts)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cached_property.py", line 73, in __get__
    return obj_dict.setdefault(name, self.func(obj))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", line 169, in contacts
    return self.root.get_default_folder(Contacts)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders.py", line 965, in get_default_folder
    for f in self._folders_map.values():
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders.py", line 928, in _folders_map
    for f in FolderCollection(account=self.account, folders=distinguished_folders).get_folders():
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 1053, in call
    shape=shape,
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 88, in _get_elements
    response = self._get_response_xml(payload=payload)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 189, in _get_response_xml
    raise rme
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 171, in _get_response_xml
    res = self._get_soap_payload(soap_response=soap_response_payload)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 227, in _get_soap_payload
    cls._raise_soap_errors(fault=fault)  # Will throw SOAPError or custom EWS error
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 261, in _raise_soap_errors
    raise vars(errors)[code](msg)
exchangelib.errors.ErrorInternalServerError: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
```

Build version :

```
Build=15.0.847.31, API=Exchange2013_SP1, Fullname=Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 SP1
```

This method is work :

```
account.root.walk() # output : <exchangelib.folders.FolderCollection object at 0x03ADCA90>
```

But when i append `filter` to it above error occurred.

```
KeyError: 'folders'
```

only `root` folder is works fine and there is nothing in it !

```
print(account.root.all())  # QuerySet(q=Q(), folders=[Root (root)])
```

Comment: @AChampion All wellknown folders are available as properties on the account, e.g. as account.root, account.calendar, account.trash, account.inbox, account.outbox, account.sent, account.junk, account.tasks and account.contacts 
from link that i refer to ...

Comment: The `KeyError` is just an artifact of `account.contacts` being a cached property. The real error is `ErrorInternalServerError` which is an exception from the server. I'm directing further discussion to the issue you opened at https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/431

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this turned out to be a misbehaving archive inbox folder. Workaround provided in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/431#issuecomment-409832287 by telling exchangelib to ignore this folder:

```
from exchangelib.folders import ArchiveInbox
from exchangelib.version import EXCHANGE_2016

# Set to something newer than your current version
ArchiveInbox.supported_from = EXCHANGE_2016
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this issue by searching for:
 exchangelib KeyError: 'inbox'
the fix for us was to upgrade past 1.11.4. The was necessary after 9:15 am PST today

Comment: upgrade what !?

Comment: exchangelib, the main library